# UINavigationbar setting shadow through appearance does not work

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to add a drop shadow to my navigationbar. The code looks like this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .black
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(white: 155/255,
                                                    alpha: 1.0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 4)
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.masksToBounds = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

But it does not work. Why is it not working and what am I missing? I don't want to extend or subclass the NavigationBar to do this.

EDIT:
I figured out that the

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.bounds
```

returns wrong values so probably thats the case but does someone know why?

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783959/how-to-add-shadow-to-navigation-bar-instead-of-default-border

Comment: thanks @Anbu.Karthik but I want to do it using appearance so the link above does not help me much

Comment: @L3M0L were you able to do it with appearance approach?

Comment: it sounds the appearance protocol will apply the shadow using the shadowImage method only

Answer (score 0):

Try below code inside your `viewDidLoad`.

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However thats not the solution I'm looking for :( I want to do it through UIAppearance so the shadow is everywhere the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

Extend `UINavigationBar` and define the desired shadow property

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    var shadow: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
                self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
                self.layer.shadowRadius = 3
                self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add the shadow from `AppDelegate` globally as

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadow = true
```

Credits [Amer Harb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35650208)